# How to retrieve the attributes sent to the subscriber?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

We have a requirement to have a copy of the email sent out to the subscriber. As ExactTarget doesn't have a copy of the final email sent, we have been thinking of using a retrieverequest to get the raw template and then populate the attributes.

My question is, is there a way that we can retrieve the attributes attached to the subscriber using RequestID?

Thanks
Mu

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this yet so can not say 100% but if you use the simple filter to return back this object it looks like it may return the rendered "view in browser" version of the email.

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-AU/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/subscribersendresult/